# CameraX custom OpenGL Video Pipeline (`UseCase`/`VideoOutput`)

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera2, android-camerax

I have an existing Camera2 app which I want to migrate over to CameraX to fix a few quirks on some Android devices (Samsungs crash a few times).

Currently, I have a custom `VideoPipeline` where I do the following:

1. Using an [`ImageReader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader), I get CPU access to the Camera Frames and run face detection on it
2. After faces have been detected, forward the Frame to my OpenGL pipeline (either via an [`ImageWriter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageWriter), or by passing the `HardwareBuffer` as an OpenGL texture)
3. In the OpenGL pipeline I draw a box around the user's face using OpenGL.
4. After I drew the box around the face, I render everything into two output surfaces:

   1. The Preview View Surface
   2. A MediaRecorder/Encoder Surface (when recording to .mp4)

In Camera2 I just attached the `surface` I get from the `ImageReader` (step 1) to the Camera, and it started streaming into my ImageReader at whatever format I configured the `ImageReader` to run at (`ImageFormat.YUV_420_888` for CPU algorithms or `ImageFormat.PRIVATE` for GPU algorithms).

> See code here: [`VideoPipeline.kt`](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/blob/main/package/android/src/main/java/com/mrousavy/camera/core/VideoPipeline.kt)

---

I've been trying to wrap my head around CameraX' quite high-level abstractions of the whole Camera pipeline, but I can't seem to understand how to create a custom Video Pipeline where I can do what I did in Camera2.

So far, this is what I came up with:

```kotlin
class VideoPipeline(
  private val format = ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, // or ImageFormat.PRIVATE
  private val callback: CameraSession.Callback
) : VideoOutput, Closeable {
  companion object {
    private const val MAX_IMAGES = 3
    private const val TAG = "VideoPipeline"
  }

  // Output
  // TODO: Use `Recording`/`Recorder` output from CameraX?

  // TODO: When I didn't override getMediaSpec, CameraX crashed.
  @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
  override fun getMediaSpec(): Observable<MediaSpec> {
    val mediaSpec = MediaSpec.builder().setOutputFormat(MediaSpec.OUTPUT_FORMAT_MPEG_4).configureVideo { video ->
      // TODO: Instead of hardcoding that, can I dynamically get those values from the Camera?
      video.setFrameRate(Range(0, 60))
      video.setQualitySelector(QualitySelector.from(Quality.HD))
    }
    return ConstantObservable.withValue(mediaSpec.build())
  }

  @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
  override fun onSurfaceRequested(request: SurfaceRequest) {
    val size = request.resolution
    val surfaceSpec = request.deferrableSurface
    Log.i(TAG, "Creating $size Surface... (${request.expectedFrameRate.upper} FPS, expected format: ${surfaceSpec.prescribedStreamFormat}, ${request.dynamicRange})")

    // Create ImageReader
    val imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(size.width, size.height, format, MAX_IMAGES)

    imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ reader ->
      val image = reader.acquireNextImage() ?: return@setOnImageAvailableListener

      // 1. Detect Faces
      val faces = callback.detectFaces(image)

      // 2. Forward to OpenGL
      onFrame(image)
    }, CameraQueues.videoQueue.handler)

    // Pass the ImageReader surface to CameraX when bound to a lifecycle
    request.provideSurface(imageReader.surface, CameraQueues.videoQueue.executor) { result ->
      imageReader.close()
    }
  }
}
```

and then to set up the Camera:

```kotlin
val fpsRange = Range(30, 30)

val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)

val videoPipeline = VideoPipeline(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, callback)
val video = VideoCapture.Builder(videoPipeline).also { video ->
  video.setMirrorMode(MirrorMode.MIRROR_MODE_ON_FRONT_ONLY)
  video.setTargetFrameRate(fpsRange)
}.build()

val camera = provider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, video)
```

..but this crashes because for some reason when calling `acquireNextImage()`, because apparently the surface producer (the Camera) is configured with format `0x1` (RGB) instead of `0x23` (YUV)?:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The producer output buffer format 0x1 doesn't match the ImageReader's configured buffer format 0x23.
  at android.media.ImageReader.nativeImageSetup(Native Method)
  at android.media.ImageReader.acquireNextSurfaceImage(ImageReader.java:439)
  at android.media.ImageReader.acquireNextImage(ImageReader.java:493)
  at com.mrousavy.camera.core.VideoPipeline.onSurfaceRequested$lambda$1(VideoPipeline.kt:99)
  at com.mrousavy.camera.core.VideoPipeline.$r8$lambda$5heGRS9RL_Z-x-BiU-ziCBMS68U(Unknown Source:0)
  at com.mrousavy.camera.core.VideoPipeline$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onImageAvailable(Unknown Source:2)
  at android.media.ImageReader$ListenerHandler.handleMessage(ImageReader.java:800)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Now especially also because of the `getMediaSpec()` method I wasn't sure if what I'm doing is the correct approach for this, does anyone have any thoughts or ideas? Multiple questions about this approach:

1. Should I extend `VideoOutput` and then use that in a `VideoCapture.Builder`, or should I directly extend `UseCase` and do everything myself?
2. Can I somehow re-use CameraX' `Recorder`/`Recording` instances in my `VideoPipeline` to stream into that Surface from OpenGL? I don't want to re-write the entire MediaMuxer/MediaEncoder parts...

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the [OverlayEffect](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media3/effect/OverlayEffect) API. It allows the app to buffer up the GPU stream and wait for the result from CPU stream before rendering a overlay on top of the GPU stream. As for the CPU stream, you can get it using the [ImageAnalysis](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis) API. Not sure how do you detect faces today but you can get face detection result using the [ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit) with the [MLKitAnalyzer](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/mlkit/vision/MlKitAnalyzer) API.

For code samples, you can check out [this prototype change](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2797834). The [SyncedOverlayEffect](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2797834/9/camera/camera-effects/src/main/java/androidx/camera/effects/SyncedOverlayEffect.java) shows how to sync the CPU stream with the GPU stream. The [OverlayFragment](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2797834/9/camera/integration-tests/viewtestapp/src/main/java/androidx/camera/integration/view/OverlayFragment.kt) shows how to use MLKitAnalyzer to get the detection result.

Comment: Thanks, but there are two problems with this approach: first it sounds like this would introduce quite a noticeable delay into the preview as we'd have to wait on frames and queue them back first, and second I cannot add an ImageAnalysis use-case because I already have preview, photo and video attached - only 3 use-cases are supported at the same time.

Comment: I tried to use `CameraEffect`/`SurfaceProcessor` which looks like it is exactly what I want - the problem is only that these APIs always use `ImageFormat.PRIVATE`. I have been using `ImageFormat.YUV_420_888` in my Camera2 app without any issues, do you think it'd also be possible to use YUV instead of PRIVATE in a Preview `SurfaceProcessor`? Would make a lot of things easier...

Comment: Using YUV as the input is not supported in the current version. The device is more efficient at processing `PRIVATE` format, that's why it's the default for Preview/VideoCapture. The ImageAnalysis output is YUV_420_888 for easy CPU access.  The delay is inevitable, because the bottleneck is the processing latency of the YUV stream. This mixed PRIVATE/YUV approach is probably faster than the alternative, depending on what your current pipeline looks like.